# How to know if a date/time string contain day or not in php?

Tags: php, date

I want to check if a date/time string contains a day or not.

I used the `date_parse()` function but it automatically adds day => 1 if it doesn't find any day.
So I couldn't know if a string contains a day or not.

For example

```php
$date = "2021-02";
```

How to know if this string contains a day or not?

Comment: How can you differentiate between months and date till 12 ? both are same from 01 to 12 ?

Comment: $date = "2021-02"; also clear is this string contain day or not ? add 2-3 examples and tell us the output as true or false as it contain day or not,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are expecting some thing like this.

```
<?php
$date1 = "2021-02";
$date2 = "2021-02-11";
$date3 = "2021-12";
$date4 = "2021-12-14";
$date1_array = explode("-", $date1);
$date2_array = explode("-", $date2);
$date3_array = explode("-", $date3);
$date4_array = explode("-", $date4);

if (count ($date1_array) == 3)
{
    echo $date1 . ": It's a Date.";
    echo "<br />";
}
if (count ($date2_array) == 3)
{
    echo $date2 . ": It's a Date.";
    echo "<br />";
}
if (count ($date3_array) == 3)
{
    echo $date3 . ": It's a Date.";
    echo "<br />";
}
if (count ($date4_array) == 3)
{
    echo $date4 . ": It's a Date.";
    echo "<br />";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php) method tests well that the format is adhered to. Entries like "2019-02-" or "2019-xx-23" are also recognized as incorrect.

```
$date = "2021-02-x";

$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$date);

if($dateTime){
  echo $date.' ok';
}
else {
  echo 'wrong date '.$date;
}
```